# Differential equation system and limit cycles

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, soft-question

I'm reading an article and it states the following:

> Then, the factor is an integrating factor of the system (referring to a certain differential equation system), hence the system is integrable and **its first integral is smooth in $\mathbb{R^2}$. So it doesn't have limit cycles.**

I don't understand this part. What theorem are they using to say from the first integral of a system that it has not limit cycles?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not a theorem, it is immediate. Just draw the curves.

Comment: The existence of a smooth first integral implies that all orbits of the system are restricted to the level curves of that integral. By smoothness, they cannot "tend" to a limit cycle @Relure

Comment: To elaborate. Let integral = $I$. Suppose on the limit cycle $I = c = const$; then take a trajectory that spirals in/out of of the limit cycle; its equation must be $I = k$ with $k \neq  c$; this contradicts smoothness @Relure

Comment: @Alex  Can you explain how the fact that the first integral is constant on the limit cycle and somewhere inside the cycle contradicts its (the first integral's, that is) smoothness?

Comment: A limit cycle  $\gamma$ has the property that there is a nearby orbit $\phi$  spiralling towards or away from  it. Suppose that the limit cycle is given by $I=c$. There is a neighbourhood of $\gamma$ where the values of the integral on the orbit $\phi$  must be tending to $c$ by continuity. However, the orbit $\phi$ eventually leaves the neighbourhood of $\gamma$ and therefore the value of the integral will differ from $c$. However by definition  the first integral must be constant on each orbit @user539887

Comment: @Alex And it is constant on each orbit (sorry, I am not a native English speaker, but I think that the use of the quantifiers in the sentence is the following: for each orbit $\phi$ there is $c =c(\phi)$ such that for any $x \in \phi$ there holds $I(\phi) = c$; and there is nothing in the sentence that excludes the case that for two different orbits the value $c$ is the same).

Comment: Let me explain plainly what I was trying to convey:  the non-existence of limit cycles is impossible, since in the definition of the first integral *it is implied* that it **cannot be constant on any open set** (in practice, first integrals are **analytic**, so it suffices to say additionally that they are not constant).  But the function $e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\ge0$ and $0$ for $x\le0$ is $C^\infty$ (so is **smooth**), and perhaps its modification could serve as a non-constant first integral for the case of orbits spiralling from inside.

Comment: In your comment, did you wish to say "existence of limit cycles is impossible", rather than "non-existence..."?. Yes, in my comment I implicitly assumed that first integrals are not constant on any open set. So you are saying that we strictly require that $I$ is $C^{\omega}$ rather than just smooth? @user539887

Comment: @Alex That was my mistake:  I meant "existence".  And I think that in the OP's question the term "integrable" is a key:  I don't know how the OP understands that, but my interpretation is that it implies that the first integral has non-zero gradient (perhaps except some isolated "singular points"). And then your argument is valid.  The last remark:  My objection (to the OP, not to you) was against the use of the term "smooth".

Comment: Ok, thanks. Actually, do you have any example / references to literature with  $C^{r}$, for $r = 1,..., \infty$, but not analytic, first integral, with the kind of behaviour you described in your comment earlier? Because all / most examples I have seen have indeed analytic integrals, except singular points @user539887

Comment: @Alex  I don't think so.  All the examples of first integrals occurring in "practical" problems that I know are analytic, perhaps with some singularities, but on one-codimensional submanifolds at most.